# Difference between multipolygon and polygon in PostGIS

Tags: gis, polygon, postgis, esri

What is the difference between `point` and `multipoint` ? `linestring` and `multilinestring` ? `polygon` and `multipolygon` ? In PostGIS

What is the secret behind defining "Multi" shapes?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"Multi" means, that several objects of that kind are "grouped" together to single object. For example, imagine Philippines. That country consists of lot of islands - you can't draw it with single polygon; and it would be inconvenient to store it as several different database rows, each containing single polygon.